# search for a node at a given position doubly linked list

Tags: java

I am trying to search for a node based on the position of the node in a doubly linked list. For example, if the list contains 1,2,3,4,5 and I want to get position 3, it will return positions data, which is 3. I was able to get the first and second position, but when I try any other position after the second, it only returns the second position. I am not sure what is wrong. Here is my code so far:

Insert Method

```
public void insertAtStart(String data)
    {
        Node ptr = new Node(data);
        if(head == null)
        {
            head = ptr;
            tail = head;
        }
        else
        {
            head.prev = ptr;
            ptr.next = head;
            head = ptr;
        }
        size++;
    }
```

Search Method

```
public Node searchAt(int pos)
    {
        Node found = head;

        if(isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("List is empty");
            return null;
        }

        if(pos == 1)
            return found;

        for(int i = 2; i <= size; i++)
        {
            if(i == pos)
            {
                found = head.next;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
```

Test:

```
        doc.insertAtStart("1");
        doc.insertAtStart("2");
        doc.insertAtStart("3");
        doc.insertAtStart("4");
        doc.insertAtStart("5");

        doc.printReverse();
        Node newNode = doc.searchAt(4);
        System.out.println("Node" + newNode.data);
```

output:

```
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
5: 5
Node: 2
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's working exactly as programmed.  Your list is actually backwards (it's stored as 5, 4, 3, 2, 1), so accessing position 4 is going to return 2.  If you inserted at the tail instead, you'd have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as the list.  Or if you inserred the data in reverse orde, it would end up as expected.  Just for clarity though, can you show the values for all the positions using searchAt()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is at this line:

`found = head.next;`

You always return the second element (and the first one works thanks to the first branch of your `if` statement).

You should instead run through the list and get the correct element.

Comment: Thank You, for some reason I couldn't figure it out. So I just advanced the head node by head = head.next;

Answer (score 3):

Tweak the for loop a bit:

- Move one position in list every iteration
- Break loop when position is reached.

  ```
  for(int i = 2; i <= size; i++)
  {
      found = head.next;
      if(i == pos)
      {
          break;
      }
  }
  ```